# How to handle storage on my t3a instances?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am very new to aws and `boto3` and I don't understand the aspect of storage on ec2 instances.

Let say I have a `t3a` instance created programatically with python like this :

```
instance = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId=AMIS[instance_region],
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        Placement={
            'AvailabilityZone':'%sa'%instance_region
        },
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        KeyName='ec2-keypair-api',
        NetworkInterfaces=[{'DeviceIndex': 0, 'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True, 'Groups': [SECURITY_GROUPS[instance_region]]}]
    )
```

Is there a default storage in my instance ? Do I need to attach an EBS Volume ? If so, How to do it considering the above context ?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened when you tried your code? Did it create the instance? You'd be able to see your instance on the ec2 dashboard with its configuration.

Not all instances use the same storage type, but the t3a is EBS and can be configured in the create_instances method using the following:

```
BlockDeviceMappings=[
    {
        'DeviceName': 'string',
        'VirtualName': 'string',
        'Ebs': {
            'DeleteOnTermination': True|False,
            'Iops': 123,
            'SnapshotId': 'string',
            'VolumeSize': 123,
            'VolumeType': 'standard'|'io1'|'io2'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1'|'gp3',
            'KmsKeyId': 'string',
            'Throughput': 123,
            'OutpostArn': 'string',
            'Encrypted': True|False
        },
        'NoDevice': 'string'
    },
]
```

If you manually create a t3a instance via the console, you will see the defaults used. It's been a while since I've done that, but you'll see what parameters you can use in the boto3 code.

Refer to the documentation for more details: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html